# Swift Combine using CombineLatest with optional publisher

Tags: swift, combine

I am new to Combine framework so my question may be simple.
I am trying to combine values from multiple publishers and send values even when received values are some publishers have not published yet.

Here is what I have for now:

```
return Publishers
      .CombineLatest(somePublisher, otherPublisher)
      .map { (somePublisherValues, otherPublisherValue) in
        return [
          somePublisher,
          otherPublisherValue
        ]
      }
      .removeDuplicates()
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Both publishers publish in all cases so it works fine.
Now I need to add a third one: thirdPublisher.

- Both somePublisher and thirdPublisher may publish
- somePublisher may not publish
- thirdPublisher may not publish

How can I send a response in all cases that is in previous cases something like:

- return [somePublisher, otherPublisherValue, thirdPublisherValue]
- return [nil, otherPublisherValue, thirdPublisherValue]
- return [somePublisher, otherPublisherValue, nil]

I tried:

```
return Publishers
      .CombineLatest3(somePublisher, otherPublisher, thirdPublisher)
      .map { (somePublisherValues, otherPublisherValue, thirdPublisherValue) in
        return [
          somePublisher,
          otherPublisherValue,
          thirdPublisher
        ]
      }
      .removeDuplicates()
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

But it does not publish as some of the publishers is not present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CombineLatest` is designed to only emit once all of its upstream publishers have emitted their 1st value. If you want to emit as soon as any of the upstreams emitted and send `nil` for all missing values, you can map all of your upstreams to emit `Optional` values and force them to send `nil` before any real values using `prepend(nil)`.

This way, you'll receive a single `[nil, nil, ...]` value before your real outputs (which you can ignore using `dropFirst`) and then you'll start receiving your desired output.

```
let publisher: PassthroughSubject<Int, Never> = .init()
let publisher2: PassthroughSubject<Int, Never> = .init()

let optionalPublisher = publisher.map(Optional.init).prepend(nil)
let optionalPublisher2 = publisher2.map(Optional.init).prepend(nil)

let combined = Publishers.CombineLatest(optionalPublisher, optionalPublisher2)

combined.sink {
  print("CombineLatest emitted \($0)")
}.store(in: &subscriptions)

publisher.send(1)
publisher2.send(1)
publisher.send(2)
```

Output:

```
CombineLatest emitted (nil, nil)
CombineLatest emitted (Optional(1), nil)
CombineLatest emitted (Optional(1), Optional(1))
CombineLatest emitted (Optional(2), Optional(1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much I read about prepend somewhere but did not found concrete example, I will try that implementation